# how to replace a fragment with another fragment in android 4.0.4

Tags: android-fragments

I try to replace a fragment with another fragment by pressing a button.
This is ***Successfull*** on **android 4.1.2**,but is ***failed*** on **android 4.0.4**
The code is:

```
if(f13!=null)
                                {
                                    transaction.remove(f13);




                                    transaction.replace(R.id.place,f10,"f10");
                                    transaction.commit();
                                }
```

where f13 and f10 are fragments.
I added this statment:

```
transaction.addBackstack(null);
transaction.replace(R.id.place,f10,"f10");
transaction.commit();
```

The app is running,**but** when i click back button in my mobile to return f13, the fragment f10 show **under** f13.
I want when i am clicking back button the app close.

Answer (score 0):

Let me be clear, you want to manage your **backstack** so that when you hit the **Back button**, your app should close.  For that issue, use **popBackStack** method of FragmentManager class. Code example using your pseudo code:

```
Fragment newFragment = new ExampleFragment();    // "f10" fragment
FragmentManager manager = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();

FragmentTransaction transaction = manager.beginTransaction();
transaction.replace(R.id.place,f10, newFragment);
transaction.commit();

manager.popBackStack();
```

If you want to remove all items in the stack:

```
manager.popBackStack(null, FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);
```

I never tried POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE. Pls keep us posted. Good luck, Tommy Kwee